# How to check out history safely?

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

In most cases checking out a previous commit is safe. But since `.gitIgnore` is version controlled as well,  checking out an old commit with an older version of `.gitIgnore` can have serious side effects.

Imagine that our latest commit includes the following files:

- `.gitignore` ignores `config.properties`
- `config.properties` our main configuration file

Since git ignores `config.properties` reverting to an older commit will keep `config.properties` as is.
But since older commit doesn't ignore config.properties it now appears as an added file.

In order to checkout the latest commit again, one can either:

- commit file
- ignore file
- remove files
- or stash files.

Each of which isn't ideal. Each comes with a side effect.

Committing files or ignoring files (updating .gitignore) creates a new head.
Removing files, or stashing them will remove those files our of version control. Meaning that when returning to our latest commit those files will be missing.

What is the safest approach to checkout a previous commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are worried about any changes to your working directory, just use `git worktree`

```
git worktree add ../<new dir> <sha or branch>
```

Edit:
sorry misremembered the syntax best to check the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)

Comment: Excellent solution. The only thing, is that since you are in a new directory, all the non versioned files won't be there, so the devlopment environment won't be available there.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the issue is that, in your scenario, `git checkout` itself may silently overwrite the content of said file.

Take the following example, where `config.properties` is actually tracked at some point in your history :

1. commit 1 : `config.properties` is added and committed in the repo
2. commit 2 : `config.properties` is removed, and a line is added in `.gitignore`
3. on your disk, you create a local `config.properties`, which is ignored by git

If, from step 3, you run `git checkout <commit 1>`, git will overwrite the content of `config.properties` with the content stored in `commit 1`.

---

If this situation could be triggered on your repo, the safest sequence of actions I would suggest is :

- run `git stash -a` *before* running `git checkout` in the first place

`git stash -a` is a quick one liner, perhaps there are some files you also don't want to stash (say: the `obj/` directory), you can select the files you want to include in that stash :

```
git stash push -a -- config.properties config/

# 'push' can be omitted :
git stash -a -- config.properties config/
```